# Detect changes made to a hidden field in the parent page from child page JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages,Let's say ParentPage.aspx and ChildPage.aspx. In the ParentPage.aspx I have a hiddenField,lets call it `hidField1`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidField1" id="hidField1" value="0" runat="server" />
```

So then I am opening the Childpage using following function in  ParentPage.aspx.

```
function myFunc(){
  var url = "ChildPage.aspx";
  window.open(url,'_blank');   
}
```

Then after doing some processing in parent page, the `hideField1` value gets changes to 1 from 0.

I need to be able to track this from the ChildPage.aspx. currently I am running a `setInterval` function with a 1000ms set as interval inside `$(document).ready(function () {...});` and following is what i have so far

```
 setInterval(function () {
            var hideField1= $("#hideField1", window.opener.document).val();
            if (hideField1 == "1") {
                console.log("change detected now reset from child!!!");
                $("#hideField1", window.opener.document).val("0");
            }
        }, 1000);
```

This works as expected and I can see from the child page when there is change in the parent page and also can change the hidden field value of the parent page from the child page. But that means this setInterval function will be running every second in order to detect this change.

How can i do this with `jQuery` **without having to use setInterval function**.Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event listeners, you can accomplish this in jQuery by doing the following;
https://jsfiddle.net/w2kLto71/

```
const hidden = $('#hidden');

hidden.on('change', function(e) {
  const target = $(e.target); // if you need jquery, if not e.target.value
  alert(target.val());
  // conditional
})
```

Comment: I apologies in advance if I haven't understood your answer but I cannot see the difference between your answer and what I have so far as this also iterate itself again and again until the value is changed in parent page. what i want to happen is trigger this function when the change happened to the hidden field in the parent page so preventing child page from running a timer to detect changes

Comment: @PissuPusa my apologies. I've updated the answer to use eventListeners, so we'll listen to the change that happens in that input.